# Format a string so values are spaced apart in txt file after it is output

Tags: java, string, format

I am in need of some minor formatting assistance as I am new to java and scratching my head at something that should be very simple. The values that the user enters in the dialog boxes is being output to a txt file. What is happening though when I open the txt file is that the values are not spaced apart. I don't need quotes around the rate and hours values but I want them spaced apart. Thanks.

```
public class OutputToAFileBrocEast
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        File file = new File("payroll.txt");      

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String name;
        String rate;
        String hours;
        String answer;

        do {

            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter first and last name: ");
            rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter hourly rate: ");
            hours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter hours for previous week: ");

            bw.write(name);
            bw.write(rate);
            bw.write(hours);
            bw.write("\n");

            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Do you have another employee? [y/n]");

        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));

        bw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If they're concatenate together, why not just add a `bw.write(" ");` between your other write commands?

Comment: See `String.format()`

Comment: I figured it out with that bit of direction. Thanks.